# Using Visualo Studio code to send message

Tags: node.js

Im using this:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');

module.exports = class ICommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('I', 'Shop', ['i','Instructions']);
  }

  run(client, message, args) {
    message.channel.send(':question: **How do i order?** :question: ');
    message.channel.send('We try to do it the easiest way. When ordering be as precise as possible,     fill out all details');
    message.channel.send('**Please fill inn the following:**');
    message.channel.send(':one: What item you want. (List everything)/fff');
    message.channel.send(':two: Pay the **BANK** the required amount.');
    message.channel.send(':three: Give additional information. Do you have gift cards or discount rank you want to use?');
    message.channel.send('*When everything is filled out an agent will complete your request.* (7)');
    message.delete()
  }
}
```

These sends as different messages after each other. But i want all the text into on message, in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Would be ok to make multiple strings with a `newline` first and then concatenate all of these to one string and only then call the message.channel.send() only once?

Maybe like this:

```js
var str1 = new String( "This is string one\n" ); 
var str2 = new String( "This is string two\n" ); 
var str3 = str1.concat(str2.toString());
console.log("str1 + str2 : "+str3)
```

Reference:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_concat.htm